# Connecting to Couchbase 2.0 cluster via libcouchbase fails, when a single node is down

Tags: couchbase

I am experiencing a weird behavior when connection to a couchbase cluster consisting of several nodes. Due to redundancy I set up the connection with multiple IPs as described in the documentation.
To track down the problem I tried to connect to a single node like this:

```
$cb = new Couchbase("<valid ip>", "<username>", "<password>", "<bucket>");
```

This works entirely fine. But when replacing the single ip by an array of ip - in order to achieve redundancy. I get the following output in my error log:

PHP Warning: Failed to establish libcouchbase connection to server: Connection failure in ...
PHP Warning: There is no active connection to couchbase in ...

The code for connecting is as follows:

```
$hosts = array(<invalid ip>, <valid ip>);
$cb = new Couchbase($hosts, "<username>", "<password>", "<bucket>");
```

In this case I get the above warning and libcouchbase does not connect at all. According to the documentation couchbase should try all provided nodes and should not die on the first "dead node".

Did I get anything wrong? Do you have any ideas for a work-around?

Thanks a bunch!
Chris

Comment: Could you specify the versions of php extension and libcouchbase? And if you have libcouchbase2-bin package installed (or from the tarball), you should have 'cbc' tool available. What does this command outputs 'cbc cp -h "<invalid ip>;<valid ip>" -u <username> -P <password> -b <bucket> /etc/passwd'

Comment: libcouchbase version is 2.0.7, version of php extension is 1.1.4dp1. When executing the above command, I get the following error:
**ERROR: Connection failure
 "Could not connect to server within allotted time"**

When connecting to a single valid node I get 

**Stored "/etc/passwd" CAS:746db695c40f0000**

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is version specific, but when I connect, I don't use an array of IPs. I use a semi-colon delimited list. e.g.

```
$cb = new Couchbase("192.168.2.1;192.168.2.2", $user, $password, $bucket);
```